# Is that a bug in xswap() in unix v6 source code?

Tags: c, unix

The function xswap is called by expand, and xswap frees the process's data segment which contains the process's kernel stack(PPDA). So if the stack is freed, how does xswap return to expand?

```
// expand()(ken/slp.c)    
expand(newsize)
{
    // ...
    a2 = malloc(coremap, newsize);
    if (a2 == NULL) {
            savu(u.u_ssav);
            xswap(p, 1, n);
            p->p_flag =| SSWAP;
            swtch();
            // no return
    }
    // ...
}
```

Comment: I don't understand what you are talking about. Can you provide some link about the context of your question or detail a little more. You ask for `xswap()` but show `expand()`. What is your point?

Comment: @Stargateur the code in question is from unix v6 source code. In the `expand()` the `xswap()` is called. but in the `xswap()`, the called stack is freed as the data segment is freed by `xswap()`.  Here is the link to `expand()` source code [slp.c](http://www.tom-yam.or.jp/2238/src/slp.c.html) and link to `xswap()`[text.c](http://www.tom-yam.or.jp/2238/src/text.c.html)

Comment: @hk768 you are looking at kernel code, but this kernel code works on user processes. When you say xswap() frees the stack, that would be on the process it's referring to, not the currently executing code.

Comment: @nos The stack the kernel is using belongs to the process's data segment. Every user process has two stacks, one for user mode and one for kernel mode. But they all belong to process's data segment.